# SQL inner join not showing expected results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to fetch all the posts made by me and my friends only. But this query shows the posts even to a user who has no friends.

```
SELECT f.user_id,f.friend_id, p.user_id AS Post_BY, p.post_text, p.post_date  
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN friends f USING (user_id) 
INNER JOIN post p USING(user_id)
WHERE f.user_id = 6 
OR f.friend_id = 6
OR p.user_id = f.user_id
```

Comment: Can you show the structure of your SQL tables please ?

Comment: Yes wait @MaximeMettey

Comment: post (post_id (PK), user_id (FK), post_text, post_date)
users (user_id (PK), user_first_name, user_last_name, email, user_password)
friends (user_id (FK), friend_id (FK), friendshipDate)

Comment: is Friend_ID a foreign key to users?

Comment: There's a `user_id` in all three tables, better change the joins from `USING` to explicit columns.

Comment: See the structure of the tables please @xQbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you want posts, so make it your primary table. Then, you could create a subselect to find all your friends' IDs.

```
SELECT p.user_id AS Post_BY, p.post_text, p.post_date 
FROM post p
WHERE p.user_id = 6
    OR p.user_id IN (SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 6)
```

This is the simplest case and assumes that for a friend relationship there are two entries in the friends table (1 > 2 AND 2 > 1).

If there is only one entry in the friends table, you need to add another query to the subquery:

```
SELECT p.user_id AS Post_BY, p.post_text, p.post_date 
FROM post p
WHERE p.user_id = 6
    OR p.user_id IN (
        SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 6
        UNION
        SELECT user_id FROM friends WHERE friend_id = 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should return: All friends posts and your own.
it assumes friends table friend_Id is a foreign key to users.user_ID. which ties to p.user_ID.  The friend.friend_Id is not explicitly defined though can be inferred from `OR f.friend_id = 6` in the original post

We join to post using an `or` condition to return your and your friends posts.
We limit to just you from the users table.

order of the tables doesn't matter, I re-arranged for my benefit in thinking this through.

```
SELECT f.user_id,f.friend_id, p.user_id AS Post_BY, p.post_text, p.post_date  
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN friends f 
  on u.user_id = f.user_id
INNER JOIN post p 
  on f.user_id = P.user_id
  or f.friend_id = p.user_id
WHERE (u.user_id = 6)
```

---

After comment saying it's not working...Lets break it down:

- Join of users to friends on user_Id should give you... yourself and friends IDs; however in two separate columns
- Joining to posts based on Friends `OR` user_ID means all your posts, as well as your friends.
- Where clause limits to just a single users and friends, user being 6.

I can't see why this wouldn't work.  So I would need a SQL fiddle example or sample data with expected results at this time; or I don't understand what you're after.

In fact: here's an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3efefc/3/0) showing it returns users and friends posts.  In this example, user 6 has two friends 1,2.  notice 6,1,2 posts are returned but 3's is not.

To handle that... we use a case statement and null out the friend ID on posts made by the original user.  Though a simple union of two sets may be more efficient and maintainable.

```
SELECT distinct f.user_id, 
case when u.user_ID = 6 then null else f.friend_id end as Friend_ID, p.user_id as `Post_BY`, p.post_text, p.post_date  
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN friends f 
  on u.user_Id = f.user_Id
INNER JOIN posts p 
  on f.user_ID = P.user_Id
  or f.friend_Id = p.user_ID
WHERE (u.user_id = 6)
```

Comment: friend table has no primary key. friend.user_id, friend,friend_id both come from user.user_id

Comment: "it isn't showing proper result" isn't really helpful, you want us to help you after all. Also, I don't see any issues with the answer except for the capital "i" and "d" in some cases, e.g. in `u.user_Id`.

Comment: It does suffer from one flaw.  the number of user posts returned will be duplicated for each friend a user has.  Notice in fiddle 6 only posted once, but it shows twice, once for each friend.  but could be fixed using a case statement as in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3efefc/7/0)